# A Function returning an array from 1 int input

Tags: c++

I made a function the returns an array like so

```
void array_function(int i){ 
int* a = NULL;
a = new int[3];
a = {i-1, i, i+1};
return a;
}
```

Now I want to call this function in the a new function

```
int main(){
int n = 3
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
//call the function
   }
}
```

I am not sure how I can call the function to give me the array, any help will be appreciated

Comment: the function returns `void`. If you have quesitons about compiler errors please inclde them in thequesiton.

Comment: @TaQuangTu You cannot return an array from any kind of function. You can return a pointer, but a pointer is not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::array` instead. It has more friendly value semantics:

```
#include <array>

std::array<int, 3> array_function(int const i) {
    return {{ i - 1, i, i + 1 }};
}

int main() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
         auto arr = array_function(i);
        // Use array
    }
}
```

Comment: why have you used "auto" and not "int"?

Comment: `auto` here means `std::array<int, 3>`.

Answer (score 1):

First your function is `void`, which translates as no-return-function. Make it return int* like 
`int* array_function(int i)` 
Now, to call the function you need to assign it to a temporary variable, which you can do work and then you should delete it. Full code:

```
int* array_function(int i){ 
    int* a = new int[3];
    a[0] = i-1, a[1] = i, a[2] = i+1;
    return a;
}

int main(){
    int n = 3;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int* a = array_function(i); // if you are going to do something with this array, which you will
        // some work with a
        delete[] a; // delete it to release memory from heap, everytime you do new, you should use delete at the end of your program
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this to create the array, since the method in your question does not have a return type assigned (void means that it returns nothing), you have to define a return type for the method to work, in this case a pointer to an array:

```
int* array_function(int i){ 
int* a = NULL;
a = new int[3];
a = {i-1, i, i+1};
return a;
}
```

And then just store the result of the method in a local variable like this:

```
int* myArray = array_function(n);
```